# Error while creating lambda function via CLI using gitlab CI (Error parsing parameter '--zip-file': Unable to load paramfile)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, gitlab-ci, aws-cli

I am deploying aws handler scripts as `zip` files in `S3` bucket. Now, I want to use this deployed zipped file in lambda function. I am doing all of this via gitlab CI.

I have the following CI:

```
image: ubuntu:18.04

variables:
    GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive
    AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: eu-central-1
    S3_BUCKET: $BUCKET_TRIAL

stages:
    - deploy

.before_script_template: &before_script_definition
    stage: deploy
    before_script:
        - apt-get -y update 
        - apt-get -y install python3-pip python3.7 zip
        - python3.7 -m pip install --upgrade pip
        - python3.7 -V
        - pip3.7 install virtualenv

.after_script_template: &after_script_definition
    after_script:
        # Upload package to S3
        # Install AWS CLI
        - pip install awscli --upgrade # --user
        - export PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin  # Add to PATH
        # Configure AWS connection
        - aws configure set aws_access_key_id $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
        - aws configure set aws_secret_access_key $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
        - aws configure set default.region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
        - aws sts get-caller-identity --output text --query 'Account'
        - aws s3 cp ~/forlambda/archive.zip $BUCKET_TRIAL/${LAMBDA_NAME}-deployment.zip
        - aws lambda create-function --function-name "${LAMBDA_NAME}-2" --runtime python3.7 --role arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:role/abc_scripts --handler ${HANDLER_SCRIPT_NAME}.${HANDLER_FUNCTION} --memory-size 1024 --zip-file "fileb://$BUCKET_TRIAL/${LAMBDA_NAME}-deployment.zip"

my_job:
    variables:
        LAMBDA_NAME: my_lambda
        HANDLER_SCRIPT_NAME: my_aws_handler
        HANDLER_FUNCTION: my_handler_function
    <<: *before_script_definition
    script:
        # - move scripts around and install requirements and zip the file for lambda deployment
    <<: *after_script_definition
```

For the CI, I have added Environment variables `$BUCKET_TRIAL` and is of the form `s3://my-folder`

When the CI file is run, it throws the following error in the end:

> Error parsing parameter '--zip-file': Unable to load paramfile
>   fileb://s3://my-folder/my_lambda-deployment.zip: [Errno 2] No such
>   file or directory: 's3://my-folder/my_lambda-deployment.zip'

I also tried changing the `--zip-file` in the last line of the `after_script` as:

```
- aws lambda create-function --function-name "${LAMBDA_NAME}-2" --runtime python3.7 --role arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:role/abc_scripts --handler ${HANDLER_SCRIPT_NAME}.${HANDLER_FUNCTION} --memory-size 1024 --zip-file "fileb:///my-folder/${LAMBDA_NAME}-deployment.zip"
```

But it still throws the same error.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Why do use `fileb://$BUCKET_TRIAL` if your code is `~/forlambda/archive.zip`? Shouldn't it be just `--zip-file "fileb://~/forlambda/archive.zip`? Not sure if `~` will expand here. May try with full path.

Comment: @Marcin Hey, I am doing that because the zipped deploy file is the the `$BUCKET_TRIAL ` (a folder in the S3 bucket)

Comment: but `file://` or `fileb://` is for local path only, not for s3. If you want s3, then i should be ` --zip-file "$BUCKET_TRIAL/....` in my view.

Comment: @Marcin I tried your suggestion `--zip-file "$BUCKET_TRIAL/${LAMBDA_NAME}-deployment.zip"`, and not it shows `--zip-file must be a zip file with the fileb:// prefix`

Comment: Have you tried my first suggestion? if  `fileb` is needed then it must be local file, not remote file on s3 file?

Comment: @Marcin I tried: `fileb:///root/forlambda/archive.zip/${LAMBDA_NAME}-deployment.zip`, but still the same error

Comment: Sorry, I'm getting a bit confused. In the `aws s3 cp` your deployment package is located in  `~/forlambda/archive.zip`. If so, then why do you have `fileb:///root/forlambda/archive.zip/${LAMBDA_NAME}` in the `create-function` command? What is `/${LAMBDA_NAME}`? Can't you use `fileb:///root/forlambda/archive.zip`? It also does not work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215514/discussion-between-junkrat-and-marcin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the discussion in chat.

The **solution** was to use

```
--zip-file fileb:///root/forlambda/archive.zip
```

instead of

```
--zip-file "fileb://$BUCKET_TRIAL/${LAMBDA_NAME}-deployment.zip"
```

The reason is that `--zip-file` requires a **local path** to a zip deployment package, rather than a remote location in s3.

From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/create-function.html):

> --zip-file (blob): The **path to the zip file** of the code you are uploading.  Example: fileb://code.zip